# Which of the following would be a useful step for verifying that the learning algorithm is running correctly?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

I couldn't answer this question(Machine Learning Course by Andrew Ng from Coursera). Please help me out and explain the reason behind the answer.

### Suppose you are using gradient descent together with backpropagation to try to minimize J($\theta$)(J(Θ) as a function of $\theta$). Which of the following would be a useful step for verifying that the learning algorithm is running correctly?

1. Plot J($\theta$), to make sure gradient descent is going downhill.
2. Plot J($\theta$). J(Θ) as a function of the number of iterations and make sure it is increasing (or at least non-decreasing) with every iteration.
3. Plot J($\theta$)J(Θ) as a function of the number of iterations and make sure it is decreasing (or at least non-increasing) with every iteration.
4. Plot J($\theta$)J(Θ) as a function of the number of iterations to make sure the parameter values are improving in classification accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

Let's make the idea clear first, J(Θ) is the loss/cost of our model that we're trying to minimize through our optimizer (gradient descent) so that we make good predictions.  Hence, in theory, our loss should keep going down with every epoch/iteration as we are updating our weights. You can already see now, that if our model is really learning something then it should produce lower and lower loss with every epoch/iteration.

You may see now that option 1 doesn't help us in analyzing our model's improvement.

At option two, our plot is okay, we're plotting J(Θ) on the y-axis and iteration on the x-axis but we don't want to make sure it's increasing, we wanna do the opposite.

At option four, again our plot is correct, however, we're not going to monitoring the weight values, they can be any value, we just want lower loss so that our accuracy gets high.

So as you can see, the correct option is 3, we're plotting the J(Θ)vsIteration plot and monitor if the loss is decreasing (or at least not increasing, because increasing means we didn't learn anything rather it got worse)